# Generate schema from file or download schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I download file from the following link:

[XML file](http://www.ishares.com/us/products/239637/ishares-msci-emerging-markets-etf/1395165510757.ajax?fileType=xls&fileName=iShares-MSCI-Emerging-Markets-ETF)

I would like to obtain schema for this file. Within a file I found

```
<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
```

I assume this is description of the schema. Does anybody know where to download this schema?

I also tried building schema from the file using [online schema builder](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html), but received error message:

```
Unable to parse any XML input. error: The element type "ss:Style" must be terminated by the
matching end-tag "</ss:Style>".
```

I know nothing about XML, but need to find a quick solution. Where can I find simple tutorial to get up to speed quickly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling for the namespace revealed that this is Microsoft Office 2003 Suite schema:

http://schemas.stylusstudio.com/msoffice2003/frames.html

Which can be downloaded here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=101

General recommendation: search for namespace URIs, they're more or less unique.